# Unusual Behavioural Pattern recognition using Timeseries database in c#

Tags: c#, database, time-series

I am working on application that it stores the absecence details(starttime, endtime, totalminutes) of the operator in a sql database. From that data, I have to detect unusual patterns like operator is absent on every friday.
I have created a sample database to work with algorithm. Now, I am reading about algorithms related to the problem. But I can not decide on the specific algorithm and also how to proceed in c# with already created database.

could some one tell me the efficient algorithms for my problem? 
Also the steps I should follow for my problem to implement an algorithm in c#?

Comment: This would entirely depend on what all the things are that you are looking for. There is no universal algorithm to check for "absence". That is what you need to get defined from the designers/application owner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not checking his absence through algorithm. I want to analyse the data (based on when & how much time he was absent).  I am looking for suggestion for better algorithms which could take timeseries data.

Comment: Which is exactly my point, you need to define your algorithm. What the algorithm will look for/analyse entirely depends on what you want out at the end of it. You will be defining the analytical properties and requirements of the algorithm